# VS2008 C++ Project Properties Application Settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, properties

I am fairly new to C++ in the VS2008 world.  I have experience with C++ up to VC++6.0 but then I converted to C#.  I now have run into a project that I need to develop using C++.

So on to my question . . . Specifically in VS2008 (C++ Project), where/how do I set the application level settings such as Version, Name, Description and Trademark?

I know in VC++6.0 there was a simple wizard to do all this but I cannot seem to find the equivalent in VS2008.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project in solution explorer, and add a resource or type Version, then fill in the details. OR, pinch a .rc file from an old vc6 project, add it to the project and edit the details in there.

Answer (score 0):

Add a version resource to the project.